# C# | Formatar Hora

Tags: c#

Preciso formatar uma data da seguinte maneira:

Ex:
08:00 -> fica 8h
08:30 -> fica 8h30

Tem como fazer isso direto pelo `DateTime.ToString()`;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simples:

```
DateTime.Parse("01/08/2017 08:30:00").ToString(@"HH\hmm")
```

Se quiser sem o 0 antes do 8, basta trocar:

```
DateTime.Parse("01/08/2017 08:30:00").ToString(@"H\hmm")
```

Comment: O `toString` aceita definição do formato - https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx